# Dojo Grid: data from store not showing, it shows just the header

Tags: dojo

I have the following code:

```
var items = [{status:"Active",comments:null,id:31,updated_by:"system",note:null},
     {status:"Pending",comments:null,id:30,updated_by:"system",note:null}];

var storeH =  new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({
                                data : {
                                      identifier:"id",
                                      items : items
                                    }
                            });

var layoutH = [
                                { field: 'id', name: 'ID', width: '20px' },
                                { field: 'comments', name: 'Comments', width: '100px' },
                                { field: 'status', name: 'Status', width: '60px' },
                                { field: 'updated_by', name: 'Updated By', width: '60px' },
                                { field: 'note', name: 'Notes', width: '100px' }
                            ];


var gridH = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
                                store: storeH,
                                autoHeight:true,
                                structure: layoutH,
                                id: "account-history-grid"
                            }, document.createElement('div'));

gridH.startup();
```

The problem is that it shows just the grid header. No other data. What could be wrong there?

Comment: Does `account-history-grid` have a set height when you call `startup()`? The data grid attempts to detect how much space it should use, and if it's inside a div with 0 height, it gets confused.

Comment: Just the autoHeight:true that's shown there. Without that, not even the header is shown.

Comment: Ah, apologies, I misread. I still believe it has something to do with DataGrid's detection of available space. See this fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/FdPt6/ If you move the `appendChild` after the `startup()`, it the grid will be borked.

Comment: That worked. startup() after placeAt() and looks fine. Thanks.